# WebSphere JNDI lookup in non managed threads

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, websphere, apache-camel, openjpa

I have a Java EE application (actually, it is an apache camel application) deployed on WebSphere Application Server 7.

My application consumes service requests from Web Services (threads started from the servlet container in WAS) and from JMS queues (not SI-BUS, but WebSphere MQ if that matters). For the JMS listener, Camel (or the underlying spring framework perhaps) initiates own threads (seems to be simple java threads more or less) to deal with JMS requests.

I also have a transactional Database attached to the application. So, in spring, I have something like this definied to grab a transaction manager (WebSphere built in JTA probably).

```
<tx:annotation-driven/>
```

So my problem is, that I get an error like this when a Camel/JMS is triggering an event in the application:

```
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: TransactionManager not found in JNDI under name java:comp/websphere/ExtendedJTATransaction
```

Seems like threads not initiated by the container itself cannot do JNDI lookups correct. Is there a way around this issue?

Comment: Well.. seems like the ideal solution to this is to plug websphere threading into camel. it should be doable: from Camel Doc: "To hook in custom thread pool providers (e.g. for J2EE servers) a ThreadPoolFactory interface can be implemented. The implementation can be set in the ExecutorServiceManager. The Factory interface is much simpler then the former ExecutorServiceStrategy and makes the job of integrators much easier." There are still some glue to be made, I have to find a way to extract the workmanager from WAS via JNDI and use it with the camel interfaces. But that is a different question

Comment: Switched approach to plug Camel jms threads into WebSphere. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579345/websphere-camel-jms-spring-taskexecutor-haninging-threads